# how to get bison to bail out for all errors

Tags: parsing, error-handling, bison

I am using Flex/Bison for a script parser which needs to break out of the parser and return a nonzero status from yyparse() for ALL ERRORS.  Every bit of documentation for Bison I can find is about recovery -- how can I write a rule set which bails (i.e., with YYABORT) rather than trying to recover?

Thanks for your collective wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to semantic errors, i.e., checks that you are doing in the semantic part of the syntax rules, then you can just invoke the `exit()` function to immediately exit the parser's executable. The parameter to `exit()` is the error code to return to the shell environment.

You may also implement `yyerror()` that would invoke `exit()` if you wish (to exit on syntax errors). This is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting.html).

Comment: Ah, I should have explicitly stated that I want the parser to exit with an error but not the process.  Thanks for this info, though.

Comment: Since you are "caged" inside Bison's C code, you do not have the "exception" option, which would have been a solution to such a case. 
But you can use setjmp from where you invoke yyparse() and then use longjmp in case of an error in the parser (either, from the semantic actions or from yyerrror).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no applicable error rule, bison will not attempt to recover and will immediately return when a syntax error is detected. So unless you explicitly attempt error recovery, the bison parser will act as you wish.

If you do attempt error recovery, you can still invoke YYABORT in an action to cause yyparse to return.

If your parser is not behaving in this way, please post more details.

If you want to force an error from the *scanner*, just return a token value which is not used in any production. That is guaranteed to create an error in the parser because the token cannot be shifted.

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed it.  Once I stripped out all the existing "error" rules, it does what you say.  It was confusing because my debugger never stopped on any of the rules that *were* there (it knows how to match the .y file to the source).

Comment: @nethack: If you want to use error productions (perhaps in order to produce better error messages), you can still put a YYABORT in the action, presumably after the error message. But you can't put it in the `yyerror()` function itself; it must go literally in the action.